# How to compare the output of a neural network with his target?

Tags: algorithms, neural-networks

I am coding a neural network implementation, but a I have problems in the design. I was wondering about how to compare the *output* with the *target*, my neural networks has three outputs

`groups = {'Iris-virginica':[0,0,1], 'Iris-setosa':[0,1,0], 'Iris-versicolor':[1,0,0]}`

I know I must translate each output to 0 and 1.

I meant if my result is `Iris-virginica` and my output is more or less: `[0.999979082561091, 0.9999918549147135, 0.9998408912106317]`, the subtraction would yield the following result:

`[-0.999979082561091, -0.9999918549147135, 0.000159]`

Is that correct, or I need to follow a different approach. Is possible train my net with 0, 1 and 2 values. Do I need to know any more?

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer: Take the predicted class to be the argmax of your output vector.

The longer answer: Since you're doing multiclass classification you should probably be using [softmax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_activation_function) output units (if I had to guess, I would guess you're using sigmoid output units). If $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the input to your output units then the softmax for the $i$th output unit is

$$ y_i = \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_{j}\exp(x_j)} $$

This output function is nice for a number of reasons.

1. since your output vector sums to 1, you can interpret it probabilistically.
2. the derivative is particularly nice in combination with a [log loss](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression) function.

Note: the further information I've provided may seen redundant since clearly

$$ \text{argmax}\{\mathbf{x}\} = \text{argmax}\{\mathbf{\sigma(x)}\} = \text{argmax}\{\mathbf{\text{softmax}(x)}\}, $$

where $\sigma$ is the elementwise logistic sigmoid function. The problem with just taking the argmax of what you have is you will likely not be optimizing the function you are actually interested in internally.

On the other hand the choice of loss function for classification isn't as [cut and dry](http://hunch.net/?p=211) as I've made it sound.

Comment: Can you write an example or a pseudocode?

Comment: @user12287, what part is giving you trouble?

Comment: I don't understand exactly how implement argmax function.

Comment: @user12287, sorry about that, perhaps I was a little sloppy. For the purposes here I simply meant the function that returns the index of the maximum value. So $\text{argmax}\{2, 5, 3\} = 2$, since 5 is the largest value and the second element.

Comment: What about the long answer? Can you give more details.

Comment: @user12287, what part?

Comment: the section about `softmax` function. I can't understand the main idea of your answer.

Comment: The main idea is this: You have a [multi-class classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) problem. It looks as if you're treating it as a regression problem. You should be aware of the differences and how they can impact your result.

Comment: I have a new question: If I have three outputs is needed to calculate three times the `Error`?

Comment: No, your loss function should deal with the fact that you have multidimensional output appropriately. In the future you should make new questions new questions.